# Going from derived estimators to their implementation in software

Tags: estimation, convergence, estimators

Estimation and Inference in Econometrics by Davidson and MacKinnon (1993 edition, the older one) on page 552, ch 16.3 'Covariance Matrix Estimation' states:

"Consequently, the matrix
\begin{eqnarray}
(n^{-1} \hat{X}'\hat{X})^{-1}(n^{-1}\hat{X}' \hat{\Omega} \hat{X})(n^{-1}\hat{X}'\hat{X})^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}
consistently estimates the probability limit of the OLS heteroskedastic covariance matrix. Of course, in practice one ignores the factors of $n^{-1}$ and uses the matrix
\begin{eqnarray}
( \hat{X}'\hat{X})^{-1}(\hat{X}' \hat{\Omega} \hat{X})(\hat{X}'\hat{X})^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}
to estimate the covariance of $\hat{\beta}$.

Now, why can we **ignore** the factors of $n^{-1}$? (They don't even cancel out.)

As a second point, what do the authors mean by $\hat{X} \equiv X(\hat{\beta})$?

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what acclaimed text you had in hand, preferably with a page number.

Comment: You might also want to give it a more informative title. Ed Leamer had something completely different in mind when he wrote [Let's take the con out of econometrics](http://www.international.ucla.edu/media/files/Leamer_article.pdf) :-)

Comment: Oh ok what would be a better title? Well, I remember reading about the "whimsical" by which Leamer I think referred to something including this variable and sometimes not. I find the dropping of the n just as random and frustrating as all the handwaviness that abounds. But am happy for a better title! ;-)

Comment: Plus I think it's conning at its best. It is in Davidson and MacKinnon therefore it's right and I am inclined to go ahead with my estimators. But I am not persuaded just conned...

Comment: It will be necessary to have a clear account of what "$\hat X$" and "$\hat \Omega$" are in order to answer this question.  (My suspicion is that the "factors of $n^{-1}$" to be ignored are involved in asymptotic expressions for these estimates, and *not* the ones in the matrix given in the first formula.)

Comment: Ok X hat is referring to the data I think D and M don't give a definition. Omega hat is the white /huber estimator i.e. sum over uhat^2 X_i X_i' (WITHOUT the one over n factor so we still wind up with an uneven number of n's that are ignored...).

Comment: @Andy I changed title to something more descriptive I think.

Comment: @Hirek good job! By the way, I really appreciate your questions here. I wish we had more people ask questions about econometrics and yours are good ones as well.

Comment: Thanks @Andy I am glad you find them relevant. :-) Yeah I am doing econometrics having migrated from math but as you can see am still in the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following NLS model:

$$y=x(\beta_0) + u \\ E(u)=0 \\ E(uu^T)=\Omega$$

The proofs are for the asymptotic variance matrix of $$n^{1/2}(\hat \beta -\beta_0),$$ but if we were to actually calculate this with software for the purpose of testing some hypotheses, we don't need the $\sqrt n$, so we leave them out. In other words, we have shown that $$\sqrt n (\hat \beta -\beta_0)$$ has variance matrix $B_{0}^{-1}M_0 B_{0}'^{-1},$ where $B$ is the "bread" and $M$ is the "meat" of the sandwich. It follows that $\hat \beta$ has an asymptotic variance matrix $n^{-1}B_{0}^{-1}M_0 B_{0}'^{-1},$ so all the $n$s would cancel. Another difference is that software would typically use some sort of finite sample correction, though that is more of an aside.

I have the newer edition, where $\hat X$ is written as $X_0$, which is the matrix of derivatives of $x(\beta)$ with respect to $\beta$, evaluated at the true value $\beta_0$. It's defined on p. 551.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dimitriy V. Masterov but why again can we leave out the factors of n? I.e. is there a compelling reason to do so other than saying we don't need them?

Comment: Practitioners care about $V(\hat \beta)$, not $V(f(\hat \beta))$.

Comment: Right, I see that but still why can we leave out n? Isn't it an important normalization to achieve some type of convergence?

Comment: I tried to clarify in the body of the answer. Maybe it would be helpful to consider a linear constant-only model, so your only parameter is the intercept, or $\hat \beta = \bar y$. You want to test the hypothesis that $\bar y = 10,$ so you need $V(\bar y)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need a variance estimate to test the null hypothesis you suggest to compute a t statistic that can be judged against a standard normal but my question here is about the mathematical intuition: Why is it that I write down an estimator 1/n {matrix operations} and conclude its plim is the desired parameter and then, when using it in C or MATLAB I exclude the factor 1/n? Like am I not programming up a different thing then?

Comment: I am not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Oh wait I did not see your addition. One sec reading it now.